# Serial.read() is getting a whole string rather than just a character?

Tags: serial

From the arduino documentation, the `Serial.read()` function is supposed to return a single character at a time from incoming serial messages. So if I program the arduino with the following:

```
#include "SPI.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char data1 = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(data1);
  }
}
```

And I open the serial monitor and send `"Hello, World!"` I would expect the received message to be the individual characters printed one at time but instead I get back the whole message. So what gives? What am I not understanding?

Comment: ... That you're printing characters until no more are available.

Comment: But shouldn't they be printed one at a time?

Comment: They *are* being printed one at a time. But how fast can you read?

Comment: Oh I see. I stuck a `delay()` in there and It makes more sense now. I am not that smart, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only think it is a string, it actually returns character by character. You can know by adding something like a delay after you Serial.print(). What the program actually does is that it receives one character each time you type one and it prints it, then the void loop repeats.